# Make 'awk' exit if it is given an empty file list from a subshell

Tags: awk, find

I run:

```
find mydir -type f -name "the_thing.txt"
```

And I get nothing (the file is not there).

Then I run:

```
awk '{print $0}' $(find mydir -type f -name "the_thing.txt")
```

And I get the shell stuck in `awk` (because the input file was not specified, and `awk` is now waiting for standard input).

How can I make `awk` (or `cat`) just print nothing and exit in case [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) does not output anything?

Comment: How about: `find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "the_thing.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk '{print $0}'`

Comment: BTW if the file pathname is deterministic, we don't have to use `find`. I would say: `[[ -f "mydir/the_thing.txt" ]] && awk '{print $0}' "mydir/the_thing.txt"` instead.

Comment: I indeed need to use the first occurrence of the file, which should be unique, but just in case, I am planning to cut with `| head -n1` in the subshell. How can I achieve that?

Comment: oh, the file can be in some subdirectory

Comment: Your posted command inidicates just a specific unique pathname. If your actual command differs, please update the question to express `some sundirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous post included the `-maxdepth 1` option which uniquifies the file path.
That is why I've asked about that. Now the option is removed and I've understood what you mean by `some subdirectory`.

Then would you please try:

```
find mydir -type f -name "the_thing.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -r awk '{print $0}'
```

Please note that the `-r` option to `xargs` suppresses the execution if the input is empty.

If you want to limit the file up to one with `head` command, you can say:

```
find mydir -type f -name "the_thing.txt" -print0 | head -n1 -z | xargs -0 -r awk '{print $0}'
```

The `-z` option to `head` was introduced in `coreutils 8.25` (around January 2016).

If your `head` command does not support the option, please say alternatively:

```
find mydir -type f -name "the_thing.txt" | head -n1 | xargs -r awk '{print $0}'
```

which is less robust against the filenames which contain blank characters.

Comment: On Linux (or other GNU `coreutils` platforms) the obvious solution is `xargs -r` but it's not POSIX.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the suggestion. I always learn a lot from your advice.